# second column in drop down menu list in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Hi I have made a web page with a navigation bar. There is mouse hover drop down menu on a navigation bar. I have take the code for this navigation bar from w3school web site. The code is

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div style="display:flex">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">List 4</a>
        <a href="#">List 5</a>
        <a href="#">List 6</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Now the problem is that I want to add second column in front of first column in the drop down list.For this I add second div but all the stuff of the second div appears in place of first div and hides the content of first div. Please tell me that how can I place the second div in next to first div so that they appear parallel to each other.Please answer this question. I will be very thank full to you.

Comment: What second div, where? Don’t show us the _original_ code and then vaguely mumble about what you have changed, but show us the _changed_ code that produces the problem.

Comment: can you please create a https://jsfiddle.net/ or a https://codepen.io/pen/ so everyone can debug and see what you have programmed?

Comment: If you just added a second element with the class `dropdown-content` in the same location, then of course this happens - because those elements are positioned _absolute_. You should perhaps rather add elements _inside_ of the existing element with that class, to get what is _inside_ that one single element, displayed in two columns.

Comment: I have edited and add another div that I have actually tried but it not worked for me. So please review my code and tell me that where I am wrong. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place it by wrapping the `.dropdown-content` div with a `flexbox`.

I have added `.wrapper` a class you can change it to whatever you like.
Here is the code:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">demo </a>
        <a href="#">demo</a>
        <a href="#">demo</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

P.S. In the same way you can create multiple, side by side divs using flexbox. You  can learn about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Itstudent if the code works for you so please upvote and highlight the tick mark for accepting the answer. This is how SO works for all. :)